# How can we Find the Total no. of Queries Fired by us in a specific period of time?

Tags: mysql

We are using a production Database and we want to know is there any way
to find out how many queries are executed in last 24 hours along with
their execution time(time taken by each query to execute) in MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the server logs of MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html

In particular, for you the [General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) seems to be most interesting.

If `general_log` is ON, then you can check the log and analyze the data. I suggest to save a copy of the file before anything happens if this contains important information for you. If `general_log` is OFF, then you have bad luck. You can also take a look at the [Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html).